# Dynamically calling a dll and method with arguments

Tags: c#, dynamic, dll, methods, invoke

Basically I'm trying to call a dll by name, instantiate an object, then call a method by name in that dll.  I'm getting an "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation." during the Method.Invoke.  I'm fairly sure my problem is with the typecasting of the arguments of the method.  I was wondering if anyone had any input on this exception.  Additionally, any suggestions on how to revise my approach are welcome.

```
public void calldll(string dllName, string typeName, string methodName, string arguments) {

    string[] argumentArray = arguments.Split(new char[] { '|' }, StringSplitOptions.None);

    Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(dllName);
    System.Type type = assembly.GetType(typeName);
    Object o = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod(methodName);
    ParameterInfo[] parameters = method.GetParameters();

    object[] methodParameters = new object[parameters.GetLength(0)];

    for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(parameters[i].GetType());
        methodParameters[i] = converter.ConvertFrom(argumentArray[i]);
    }

    method.Invoke(o, methodParameters); }
```

Comment: Alternately I have tried calling static dll methods by removing the "Object o = Activator.CreateInstance(type);" and changing to "method.Invoke(null, methodParameters);" with the same exception being thrown.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found two issues with your code:

1. You are not looping over all `parameters`. You should remove `-1` from the `for` loop.
2. When you are creating your converter, you call the `GetType()` method. This returns the `Type` of the `ParameterInfo` object, not the `Type` of the parameter. Use the property `ParameterType` instead.

All in all, change the first lines in the `for` loop to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Length; i++)
{
   var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(parameters[i].ParameterType);
```

Once you have done these corrections, I believe your code should run as intended. At least it did for me when I tested a simple `void Hello(int x, string y)` method.