# Invoke function from DLL with parameters

Tags: c#, dll, invoke, shellcode

I try to invoke and load functions from an Shellcode looks like that

```
public static byte[] uc = { 
0x4D,0x5A,0x90,0x00,0x03,0x00};//example
```

In this code are my classes and functions

I have found some invoke methods for dll files ,but how to load the functions from my shellcode(Shellcode from an c# dll)?

As example:

I have an dll and get an shelcode from it via

```
public static void WriteShell()
    {
        using (StreamWriter fs = new StreamWriter("shellcode.cs"))
        {
           byte[] Data = ReadFile("now.dll", GetSize("now.dll"));
              int  Size = GetSize("now.dll");
            fs.Write("public static class ShellCode\n{\n\t");

            fs.Write("public static byte[] ucShell = {\t");
            for (int i = 0; i < Size; ++i)
            {
                if (i != 0)
                {
                    fs.Write(',');
                }

                if ((i % 15) == 0)
                    fs.Write("\n\t");

                fs.Write("0x" + Data[i].ToString("X2"));
            }
            fs.Write("};");
            fs.Write("\n\n\tpublic const int ulSize = {0};\n", Size);
            fs.Write("}");
        }
```

the output is like this

```
  public static byte[] uc = { 
0x4D,0x5A,0x90,0x00,0x03,0x00};
```

in the dll i have a class and some functions, example a msgbox or something similar.

example:

```
public static class now
{
static void run()
        {
            Messagebox.Show("test");
        }

}
```

now i try to call this function with an invoke like this,
[Dynamically calling a dll and method with arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11886845/dynamically-calling-a-dll-and-method-with-arguments)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Look up how to use DllImportAttribute.

Comment: This may help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1228348/3537915

Comment: i hope my edit clearify the problem. sorry my english is not the best :)

Answer (score 0):

You can load an assembly from a byte[]. Load the assembly, then use reflection to find the function you want to call.

```
    var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(uc);
    var nowType = assembly.GetType("now");
    nowType.InvokeMember("run", ...)
```

Comment: yes its like here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19911/Dynamically-Invoke-A-Method-Given-Strings-with-Met  but how to do it whit my byte[] ?

Comment: @greenhorn I edited the code, now you have the type, and can do something similar to the codeproject article

Comment: yes i have this    

  Assembly ba = Assembly.Load(uc);
            Type t = ba.GetType("Run");
            MethodInfo m = t.GetMethod("HandleRun");
            object Result = (bool)m.Invoke(null, new object[] {"", string.Empty, file, true });
But this dont work it trow me Object reference not set to an object instance

Answer (score 0):

So far

Now i have tryed this

```
 RuntimeHelpers.GetObjectValue(Assembly.Load(uc).GetType("Classname").GetMethod("Functionname").Invoke(null, new object[] { "some ", "params", true, "blabla" }));
```

maybe i need pause..... -.-

Okay now i have it, it was my fold i had forgett to declare the namespace ..... 
Thank you guys for your help!!!